# Position of UIImageView in storyboard issue

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, uistoryboard

I have placed UIImageView in storyboard view. At the center position. I am not using autolayout. 
When I run the app. The UIimage origin is set at position (0,0) by default.

I need to position it where I set it in storyboard. It is getting updated automatically.

Please help me to solve the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if I understood your problem right... but if the UIImageView isn't positioned at the location you'd expected, you should check your autoresizing constraints in storyboard.